# Infromatica powercenter 9.* remove blank first name and last name

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I am fresher in ETL, am using Informatica Powercenter 9.*.

I have one CSV file in source and out putting same in Target. Columns are First name, Last name, Contact No.

I want to remove records whose first name and last name is blank. Which transformation should I choose, filter? Expression? or is there anything inbuilt in informatica? Also how can I remove (, ), -, + from the Contact no column during transformation.

For e.g. +1(123) 456-789 should be 123456789 in the Target CSV file.

Can anyone share which transformation is best suitable for these data modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for removing the characters you can adapt following to your needs REG_REPLACE(fieldname, '[^0-9]')

alternately you can play with the substr() and replacechr() for same effect

for the filter the best thing to do is filter it out with a filter condition on the source qualifier like

FIELDNAME1 IS NOT NULL AND FIELDNAME2 IS NOT NULL

again you can adapt depending on whether you want to filter out those records where both names are null or for scenario where either are null

(then anything which fails the filter condition will not pass through)

Comment: This worked (first_name != '' AND last_name != '') for removing blank names and REG_REPLACE(phone1,'[^0-9]','') for removing non-numeric characters. Thanks!